# Конструкторы. Как правильно реализовать наследование от Array

Tags: javascript, массивы, конструктор-копирования

хочу поинтересоваться можно ли в обще унаследовать свойства конструктора Array, так чтобы свойство length в конструкцией цикла "for in" не отображалось

```js
function MYArray(){} // объявляю функции конструктор "MYArray"
MYArray.prototype = new Array() // наследую свойства конструктора Array

var arr = [] //new Array()
var test_arr = new MYArray() // присваиваю переменой  "test_arr" свойства  конструктора MYArray
 test_arr.push(1) // методом push добавляю в массив "test_arr" свойство   0:1
 arr.push(1) // методом push добавляю в массив arr свойство 0:1
console.log(test_arr.length) // по видения переменой test_arr схоже с по видением  Array (нумерованного массива) . также изменяется значение ключа длинны массива
console.log(arr.length)
console.log(test_arr.hasOwnProperty('length')) // true // указывает что  свойства объекта принадлежит первой открытой ветке
console.log(arr.hasOwnProperty('length')) // true // указывает что  свойства объекта принадлежит первой открытой ветке
for(let key in arr){ // конструкцией цикла "for in" прохожусь по свойством открытых веток
 console.log(key) // свойство length массива arr экранируется и не выводиться
}
for(let key in test_arr){ // конструкцией цикла "for in" прохожусь по свойством открытых веток
 console.log(key) // свойство length массива test_arr отображается !! экранирования не происходит !!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в *специальном* свойстве `length`.

в обычном случае - это свойство самого массива, с выставленным свойством `enumerable` в значение `false`. Поэтому оно не выводится при обходе с помощью `for..in`.

В случае в вопросе все несколько интересней: метод [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) изменяет значение свойства `length`, при изменении свойство `length` создается в самом объекте, а не в прототипах. По умолчанию поля создаются с выставленным свойством `enumerable` в значение `true`, поэтому имя свойства и выводится при обходе с помощью `for..in`.

Для решения, достаточно просто объявить это свойство вручную и задать `enumerable` в значение `false`

```js
function MYArray() {
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'length', {
    enumerable: false,
    writable: true,
    value: 0
  });
} // объявляю функции конструктор "MYArray"
MYArray.prototype = new Array() // наследую свойства конструктора Array

var arr = [] //new Array()
var test_arr = new MYArray() // присваиваю переменой  "test_arr" свойства  конструктора MYArray
test_arr.push(1) // методом push добавляю в массив "test_arr" свойство   0:1
arr.push(1) // методом push добавляю в массив arr свойство 0:1
console.log(test_arr.length) // по видения переменой test_arr схоже с по видением  Array (нумерованного массива) . также изменяется значение ключа длинны массива
console.log(arr.length)
console.log(test_arr.hasOwnProperty('length')) // true // указывает что  свойства объекта принадлежит первой открытой ветке
console.log(arr.hasOwnProperty('length')) // true // указывает что  свойства объекта принадлежит первой открытой ветке
for (let key in arr) { // конструкцией цикла "for in" прохожусь по свойством открытых веток
  console.log(key) // свойство length массива arr экранируется и не выводиться
}
for (let key in test_arr) { // конструкцией цикла "for in" прохожусь по свойством открытых веток
  console.log(key) // свойство length массива test_arr отображается !! экранирования не происходит !!
}
```

---

Начиная с ES6, встроенные типы можно расширять используя ключевые слова `class` и `extends`. В этом случае все еще проще:

```js
class MYArray extends Array {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
} // объявляю функции конструктор "MYArray"


var arr = [] //new Array()
var test_arr = new MYArray() // присваиваю переменой  "test_arr" свойства  конструктора MYArray
test_arr.push(1) // методом push добавляю в массив "test_arr" свойство   0:1
arr.push(1) // методом push добавляю в массив arr свойство 0:1
console.log(test_arr.length) // по видения переменой test_arr схоже с по видением  Array (нумерованного массива) . также изменяется значение ключа длинны массива
console.log(arr.length)
console.log(test_arr.hasOwnProperty('length')) // true // указывает что  свойства объекта принадлежит первой открытой ветке
console.log(arr.hasOwnProperty('length')) // true // указывает что  свойства объекта принадлежит первой открытой ветке
for (let key in arr) { // конструкцией цикла "for in" прохожусь по свойством открытых веток
  console.log(key) // свойство length массива arr экранируется и не выводиться
}
for (let key in test_arr) { // конструкцией цикла "for in" прохожусь по свойством открытых веток
  console.log(key) // свойство length массива test_arr отображается !! экранирования не происходит !!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, собака зарыта где-то в том, что `test_array` не массив. Проверяется легко `Array.isArray(text_array)` — возвращает `false`.
Дело в том, что оператор `new` всегда создает экземпляр Объекта. Далее, при вызове `for..in` по цепочке прототипов находит `length`. Чтобы не затрагивать унаследованные свойства добавляют проверку:

```
for(var prop in object) {
// если свойство унаследовано - continue
if (!object.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue
// работа с prop
...
}
```